STM8S003 TIM1 prescaler seemingly not affecting anything
I'm trying to use an STM8S003 chip for a pretty basic function, so I'm standing up the TIM1 peripheral to use output compare. Everything seems to be functioning correctly, except that the pre-scaler doesn't seem to be doing anything. The code as it currently stands enables CCR1 and watches for it to trigger every 0xFF00 clock counts, at which point it toggles an LED and resets the timer count. The pre-scaler value is set to 0x07D0, which should set the clock frequency to the default internal frequency of 2 MHz / (2000+1) = 1 kHz. If that was working correctly, the LED would toggle roughly every minute. Instead, it is toggling around 30 times a second, supporting the theory that the clock frequency TIM1 is using is still 2 MHz and the pre-scaler is not doing anything. Also supporting this is that the LED frequency doesn't appear to change when I change the pre-scaler register values. What am I doing wrong?I'm using STVD to program and debug. Using the debugger I can see that my register writes are all working properly, the correct values are there and the CCR1 interrupt triggers at the correct CCR1H/L register values.
/* MAIN.C file
 * 
 * Copyright (c) 2002-2005 STMicroelectronics
 */
#include "main.h"

volatile uint8_t reader = 0;
volatile uint8_t countHigh = 0;
volatile uint8_t countLow = 0;
volatile uint16_t counter = 0;
bool ioj = 1;

int delays(uint32_t counter){
    uint32_t mult = counter * 52142;
    while(mult){
        mult--;
    }
    return 0;
}

void Timer1Init(void){
    TIM1->CR1   = 0b00001000; //Use timer as up counter
    TIM1->CR2   = 0b00000000;
    TIM1->SMCR  = 0b00000000;
    TIM1->ETR   = 0b00000000;
    TIM1->IER       = 0b00000000;
    TIM1->CCMR1 = 0b00010000; //OC1REF rising edge
    TIM1->CCMR2 = 0x00;
    TIM1->CCMR3 = 0x00;
    TIM1->CCMR4 = 0x00;
    TIM1->CCER1 = 0b00000001; //OC1 is active
    TIM1->CCER2 = 0x00;
    TIM1->CNTRH = 0x00;
    TIM1->CNTRL = 0x00;
    TIM1->PSCRH = 0x07; //Set PSCLR to 2000
    TIM1->PSCRL = 0xD0; //CLK freq = 2MHz / (2000+1) = 1 kHz
    TIM1->ARRH  =   0xFF;
    TIM1->ARRL  = 0xFF;
    TIM1->RCR   = 0b00000000; 
    TIM1->CCR1H = 0xFF; //Placeholder
    TIM1->CCR1L = 0x00; //CCR1 = 15625, 0.5s
    TIM1->CCR2H = 0x00;
    TIM1->CCR2L = 0x00;
    TIM1->CCR3H = 0x00;
    TIM1->CCR3L = 0x00;
    TIM1->CCR4H = 0x00;
    TIM1->CCR4L = 0x00;
    TIM1->BKR   = 0x00;
    TIM1->DTR   = 0x00;
    TIM1->OISR  = 0x00;
}
    
void resetTimer1(void){
    TIM1->CR1 = 0x08;
    TIM1->CNTRH = 0x00;
    TIM1->CNTRL = 0x00;
    TIM1->CR1 = 0x09;
}
    
int main(void)
{
    GPIO_config();
    enableInterrupts();
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_MODE_OUT_OD_LOW_FAST);
    GPIO_WriteHigh(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_4);
    GPIO_Init(GPIOC, outputPin, GPIO_MODE_OUT_OD_LOW_FAST);
    GPIO_WriteLow(GPIOC, outputPin);
    delays(2);
    CLK->ICKR = 0b00000001; //Use internal clock (2MHz by default)
    Timer1Init();
    TIM1->CR1 = 0b00001001; //Enable TIM1
    while(1){
        countHigh = TIM1->CNTRH;
        countLow = TIM1->CNTRL;
        counter = (countHigh << 8) + countLow;
        reader = TIM1->SR1; //See if CCR1 interrupt has triggered
        if(reader == 2){
            if(ioj){
                GPIO_WriteHigh(GPIOC, outputPin);
                ioj = 0;
            } else {
                GPIO_WriteLow(GPIOC, outputPin);
                ioj = 1;
            }
            resetTimer1();
            TIM1->SR1 = 0x00;
        }
    }
}


Answering my own question here in case someone needs this in the future:I got it working by setting the UG bit in the EGR register. I'm a little confused as to why this is necessary - I'm guessing that the registers I see in the debugger are just the preload registers and not the shadow registers, which would explain why the behavior I see doesn't match the registers I see. However, I did have events triggering without manually doing so, therefore I had assumed my code should have functioned correctly after the first event trigger ie at the first LED toggle. Not sure why it doesn't.
